# Material colorControlHighlight on pre lollipop

Tags: android

I can't figure out how to get my list buttons (from ListView) and scroll bounds effect use colorControlHighlight theme color on pre lollipop

here's my theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

v21:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccentTransparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

list fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/page1">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.FilterTabTextAppearance"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list row item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/route_thumb"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/route_thumb"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/route_sponsor_logo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/route_thumb"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/route_sponsor_logo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/route_activity_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/route_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_color"
            android:stepSize="0.5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.openrunner.android.views.OpenrunnerTextView
        android:id="@+id/route_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:fontName="OpenSans"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.openrunner.android.views.OpenrunnerTextView
            android:id="@+id/route_length"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontName="OpenSans"/>

        <com.openrunner.android.views.OpenrunnerTextView
            android:id="@+id/route_ascent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ascent_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:fontName="OpenSans"/>

        <com.openrunner.android.views.OpenrunnerTextView
            android:id="@+id/route_descent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/descent_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:fontName="OpenSans"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/route_sponsor_logo"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:scaleType="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list fragment class:

```
public class TabRoutesFragment extends ListFragment
{
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private RoutesAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_routes, container, false );
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated( View view, Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onViewCreated( view, savedInstanceState );

        tabLayout = ( TabLayout ) view.findViewById( R.id.tabLayout );
        final TabLayout.Tab routesTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        final TabLayout.Tab favoritesTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        final TabLayout.Tab gpxTab = tabLayout.newTab();


        routesTab.setText( R.string.routes_my_routes );
        favoritesTab.setText( R.string.routes_my_favorites );
        gpxTab.setText( R.string.routes_imported_gpx );

        tabLayout.addTab( routesTab, 0 );
        tabLayout.addTab( favoritesTab, 1 );
        tabLayout.addTab( gpxTab, 2 );
        tabLayout.setEnabled( false );

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener( new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected( TabLayout.Tab tab )
            {
                if( adapter != null ) adapter.getFilter().filter( String.valueOf( tab.getPosition() ) );
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected( TabLayout.Tab tab )
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected( TabLayout.Tab tab )
            {

            }
        }  );

        LinearLayout tabLayoutView = ( LinearLayout ) tabLayout.getChildAt( 0 );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
            LinearLayout tabView = ( LinearLayout ) tabLayoutView.getChildAt( i );

            if ( i == 0 ) tabView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.filter_tab_rounded_left_background_selector );
            else if ( i == 2 )
                tabView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.filter_tab_rounded_right_background_selector );
            else
            {
                final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                int margin = ( int ) ( scale + 0.5f );
                ( ( ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams ) tabView.getLayoutParams() ).setMargins( -margin, 0, -margin, 0 );
                tabView.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.filter_tab_rounded_center_background_selector );
            }

            TextView textView = ( TextView ) tabView.getChildAt( 1 );
            textView.setTypeface( FontCache.getTypeFace( getActivity(), "DarwinLight-Regular.ttf" ) );
        }

        //setListShown( false );



        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl( getString( R.string.api_url ) )
                .addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create() )
                .build();

        RouteApiInterface service = retrofit.create( RouteApiInterface.class );

        Call< Routes > routes = service.getUserRoutes();
        routes.enqueue( new Callback< Routes >()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse( Call< Routes > call, Response< Routes > response )
            {
                //for ( RouteDetails route :  )
                //{
                //    adapter.add( route );
                //}
                adapter = new RoutesAdapter( getActivity(), 0 , response.body().getRoutes() );
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                setListAdapter( adapter );

                tabLayout.setEnabled( true );
                //setListShown( true );
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure( Call< Routes > call, Throwable t )
            {

            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick( ListView l, View v, int position, long id )
    {
        super.onListItemClick( l, v, position, id );

        Intent intent = new Intent( getActivity(), RouteDetailsActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( RouteDetailsActivity.EXTRA_ROUTE_ID, adapter.getItem( position ).getId() );

        startActivity( intent );
    }
}
```

On post lollipop my list button use colorControlHighlight as expected and i wish it does the same on pre lollipop, but actually on Kitkat it's always grey and on JellyBean it's always blue.

[render preview on each SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI20e.png)

Is there any colorControlHighlight equivalent on pre lollipop?

Comment: How are you creating your Button? Can you include that XML?

Comment: just edit my post with more content

Comment: The list row item you posted seems to be missing its outermost layout

Comment: Fixed but nothing special here